# Spring integration jpa repository tests don't work as it should

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, integration-testing

I have something really strange. I want to test my repository level and I need to test if I can save 2 users with the same username(username field is unique in the database). And there is my db configuration.

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/tutorial_test
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=root

# General JPA properties
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

#Note: The last two properties on the code snippet above were added to suppress an annoying exception
# that occurs when JPA (Hibernate) tries to verify PostgreSQL CLOB feature.
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults = false

# Hibernate Specific properties
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=false
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

My entity class User:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_id_seq_gen", sequenceName = "user_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_id_seq_gen")
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 4, max = 50)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 6, max = 50)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 100)
    @NotNull
    @Length(min = 6, max = 50)
    private String email;
}
```

UserRepository:

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    boolean existsByUsername(String username);
    boolean existsByEmail(String email);
    User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

And finally my test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Before
    public void insertData() {
        user = new User(null, "Daimon", "123123", "krikkk998@mail.ru");
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @After
    public void cleanData(){
        user = null;
        userRepository.deleteAll();
    }

    @Test(expected = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)
    public void registerUserWithExistingUsername() {
        val user = new User(null, "Daimon", "123123", "glass999@mail.ru");
        userRepository.save(user);
    }

}
```

This test classes behavior is very strange. It throws an exception that it can't save another entity because the username is unique only after `userRepository.deleteAll();` Why?? Ok, if I delete `@After` method, it doesn't throw the exception at all...And again, if I add `System.out.println(userRepository.findAll());` after saving second user, it thowrs exception... What is going on here?? 
These all method works well when I start an application. But in these integration repositories tests something wrong. I have another repository tests class where I can save parent object with a set of UNSAVED childs, and when I select parent object from the database, it gives me set of childs with NULL ids...
I don't know what is the problem, but I think maybe in configuration?? Because I repeat, there is no problem when I start application and all works very well. I would be glad if you help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you see is a side effect of how JPA gets implemented. When you `persist` or `merge` an entity most people think of it as *saving* the entity. And that's why the `Repository` method which calls these methods is called `save`.

But there is no insert to the database happening at that stage (1). Instead the entity is just tracked and it will get flushed on certain events:

1. A commit of the transaction.
2. An explicit call of flush.
3. Depending on your configuration, possibly before a query (which seems to be the case here).
    That is why you get the exception on calling `findAll`.
    The implementation of `deleteAll` actually involves a `findAll` so it triggers the exception as well.

(1) actually, an `insert` might happen depending on your ID generation strategy.

Comment: Yes) thanks. I've already remembered that transaction rollbacks in tests) and the data doesn't flush. I've wanted to answer, but you answered) thanks)

Answer (score 0):

`@Before` runs before your test is run. Here it inserts a User with the Username 'Daimon'

`@Test` is your test. It tries to insert a user with the username 'Daimon' which already exists (because it was inserted in `@Before`. This is why the exception is thrown.

`@After` runs after your test. It deletes all users.

Comment: I know it. But I said that it throws such exception after deleting all objects in the table. And it doesn't throw the exception if I remove @After method.